# Upgrade from LatLonType to LatLonPointSpatialField

Tags: solr, geospatial, spatial, boosting

I am using Solr 6.5.1

LatLonType is now deprecated (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html)
and I'm trying to use the LatLonPointSpatialField. I also need it to be multi-valued.

My field is defined as follows:

`<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>`

I used to boost on my LatLonType field before like that:

`boost=recip(geodist(sfield,45.15,-93.12),3 ,10000,3000)` (I am using eDisMax).

After I changed the spatial data type, I'm getting this error:

`A ValueSource isn't directly available from this field. Instead try a query using the distance as the score.` which I don't understand.

The documentation tells nothing about using the `geodist` function with edismax to use it in `boost=` parameter. Instead it just suggests to use the function value for sorting:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-geodist

However this will not work for me, I don't need to sort on distance, I want the `geodist()` function to be multipled with score to change the resulting score.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:

**Before (LatLonType):**

`boost=recip(geodist(coordinates_ll,49.175,-123.003),1,10,1)`

**After (LatLonPointSpatialField):**

`boost=recip(geodist(),1,10,1)&pt=49.175,-123.003&sfield=coordinates_ll`